# Dynamics 365 reactivate lead

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

In the unified interface, when I click on the standard button "**Reactivate**" in the Lead form in order to reopen a qualified Lead, I have a confirmation window that asks what must be the `statuscode` of the lead, once reopened. In other organizations, I don't have this window, and this difference does not depend on the presence or not of custom statuscodes.

I want to define the `statuscode` of the reopened lead within a plugin: Is it possible to prevent the display of the confirmation window?

[image]

Comment: are you sure the popup window is not your custom implementation? screenshot pls

Comment: @Arun Vinoth I have added a screenshot, yes it is not a custom window

Comment: you mentioned its not there in other organizations. pls compare the Ribbon customizations between the orgs.making sure we are talking about the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/sales-enterprise/re-open-lead-sales

Comment: @Arun Vinoth yes it is the reactivate button, thank you, for the  moment the client is not complaining about this problem so I'll put it in standby.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha! You have to check in your Lead entity `Status Reason` transitions. If more than one `Status Reason` defined under Active state, this window will popup.

[image]

> if this xxxx needs to be activated again, then on Activation, it will ask for the status reason you want that to be on as we have mentioned many status reasons

[Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/06/custom-state-model-transitions-in-spring-release-for-dynamics-crm-2013/)

You can simply uncheck the `Enable Status Reason Transitions` so this popup will not appear and you can do this your plugin. But required validations may fail.

> When you edit a status reason field the **Edit Status Reason Transitions** button is in the menu. When you click this button the Status Reason Transitions dialog provides the option to choose **Enable Status Reason Transitions**. When this option is selected you must define which status reason values are allowed for each status reason. To remove the filtering applied, remove the **Enable Status Reason Transitions** selection. The transitions you have defined will be kept but not applied.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/define-status-reason-transitions#edit-status-reason-transitions)

[image]

Comment: Btw I tested in CRM online v9 classic UI for case entity. But Lead entity does not have transitions at all. weird!